# transformed image should always visible

Tags: matlab, transformation, interpolation, affinetransform

I am trying to transform an image using Bi-linear interpolation, my input image is `I`, I have my affine matrix `[A]`, which will give me transformed image `I'`, according to bi-linear interpolation I am taking inverse of affine matrix `inv([A])` and applying that to every point of output image(which is all zero at initial level), as we cant guarantee that output image size can be of any size, so first I found the bounds so I can get the size of the output image,

Now I have input image, Affine matrix, and output image which have atleast that size in which transformed image can be saved easily, **But**  If I apply backward backward method of warping, according to that I have to iterate through every pixel of output image(which is zero right now), I want my transformed image at the center so my transformed image should always be visible, any idea how can I do that ?

Note I don't want to use matlab's built in function.

**EDIT**
[image]

If I transformed my `A` Image I got B, but You see corner of the image got cropped, I want those to be shown as well.

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you want from the description, but perhaps you could show how far you have come where exactly you get stuck?

Comment: I want my transformed image to be completely visible. If I create my new image of same size as input image, then my transformed image seems like it is cropped.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot, or better yet some short code that will enable the problem to be reproduced? You may want to start with `im=image` to load an example image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When rotating a rectangle from the upright position to a diagonal one, the vertical distance between the highest and lowest point will increase.

Now there are two approaches you can take:

- Put the new picture in a bigger environment

OR

- Rescale the rotated picture to make it fit in the original sized environment.

Comment: That´s true. I did something similar, and my alternative was to estimate the size of the rotated image and then put it into the bigger layout. Another option is to create a very big layout, and then remove the lateral black strips that you don´t like. If you rescale it, take into account that quality will decrease.